# Maven plugin for clean the tomcat target folder and war file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I want to know how can i remove the target folder and war file which created within webapps folder when i deploy the project.

I'm using eclipse IDE for the deploy project. I want to what is the maven plugin for this goal.

But if I used terminal for deploy the project i can used. But sometimes this command also unable to clean the webapps folder.

```
mvn clean compile war:war
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error message when using `mvn clean` ?

Do you have open files which are located in the structure under `target`? This prevents the target folder from being deleted.

Comment: @Uirich I didnt open target folder. I deploy the project using eclipse IDE.